# An identity of determinant.

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider a block matrix
\begin{align}
& M = \left( \begin{matrix} X & T_1 \\ T_2 & x \end{matrix} \right),
\end{align}
where $X$ is an $n \times n$ matrix, $T_1$ is an $n \times 1$ matrix, $T_2$ is an $1 \times n$ matrix. Do we have
\begin{align}
\det(M)= x \det(X-T_1 x^{-1} T_2 )?
\end{align}
Thank you very much.

Comment: Try the special case where both $T_1$ and $T_2$ are zero. In that case, the determinant is easy to calculate. Compare with the claimed formula. Alternatively, consider the case $n=1$.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Block_matrices

Comment: $X-T_1x^{-1}T_2$ is a particular case of **Schur's complement,** an important actor in matrix algebra.